# python maze recurrsion not recurssing

Tags: python, recursion, maze

I'm trying to solve a maze recursively and I can get it to go where I want it to (check to make sure it can go a way and then to mark it as been there) but for some reason when it runs into a dead end, it does not recursively go back to an open place to check another path. Is there anything wrong with the way I'm using recursion?

```
class maze(object):
    def __init__(self, maze):
        self.maze = maze
        self.maze2d = []
        n = 0
        i = 0
        for row in self.maze:
            self.maze2d.append([])
            print(row)
            for col in row:
                self.maze2d[i].append(col)
            i += 1
        print(self.maze2d)

    def find_start(self):
        x = 0 
        y = 0
        for row in self.maze2d:
            for index in row:
                if index == "S":
                    self.maze2d[x][y] = index
                    return x,y
                y += 1
            x += 1
            y = 0
        return -1

    def mazeSolver(self,x,y,path):
        if self.maze2d[x][y] == "E":
            return True
        else:
            if self.maze2d[x] != 0: 
                if self.maze2d[x+1][y] == ".":
                    self.maze2d[x+1][y] = "_"
                    self.mazeSolver(x+1,y,path + "S")
            if self.maze2d[x] < len(self.maze2d):
                if self.maze2d[x-1][y] == ".":
                    self.maze2d[x-1][y] = "_"
                    self.mazeSolver(x-1,y,path + "N")
            if y < len(self.maze2d[x]): 
                if self.maze2d[x][y+1] == ".":
                    self.maze2d[x][y+1] = "_"
                    self.mazeSolver(x,y+1,path + "E")
            if self.maze2d[y] != 0:
                if self.maze2d[x][y-y] == ".":
                    self.maze2d[x][y-1] = "_"
                    self.mazeSolver(x,y-1,path + "W")
```

and where I'm calling the function and the maze itself:

```
from eachstep import *

maze1 = []

maze1.append("S..*..")
maze1.append("*...*.")
maze1.append("..*..E")

var1 = maze(maze1)
x,y = var1.find_start()
var1.mazeSolver(x,y,"")
```

Comment: To clarify, what do the characters `.` and `*` represent?

Comment: @Jen Did you forget to `return` at the recursive point?

Comment: Before you search for x+1 or x-1 you should verify that you are not at the end or the beginning of that line. The same for y

Comment: Oops, sorry, been staring at it too long :p . is an open path, * is a wall. S is start, E is end.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic - I realize I need to return at the end (once it gets to the end, to return the actual path), the problem is I've been trying to debug it, and when I walk through, from the left of the start, it goes south 3 times until it runs out of room. Instead of going to the recursive call before to try a different route, it just freaks out bc it has no where to go and ends.

Comment: side note: Python lacks the tail call optimizations common in functional languages and has a relatively low default limit for recursion (999 calls). I dare to say that recursive code is not idiomatic in Python, and every recursive algorithm should be converted to its iterative version (not hard), otherwise the program will crash depending on the data size.

Comment: @PabloReyes I have those perimeters in there, the 4 if statements before each direction to verify it can check it

Comment: @Jen I think conditions like this one `if self.maze2d[x] < len(self.maze2d):` is problematic, it seems to me you are comparing a list to an integer.

Comment: @PauloScardine - why would I need to do that? My understanding of recursion is that if one of the functions ends, it will trace back to the previous one automatically. My program isn't anywhere near the amount of 999 calls, so do you think it would still need to be changed?

Comment: @Jen. When executing your original code, I was having error:"""IndexError: list index out of range""". That's what I had to revise your way of checking if you were at the beginning or end of a row or column.

Comment: @Jen: if you are using a recursive algorithm, I would not consider the program correct unless you make sure the stack will never be higher than 999 calls. For example, assuming the number of recursive calls is related to the maze size, you must place a cap on the maze size. But that is me, I'm a nittypicker..

Answer (score 1):

I changed your mazeSolver function with this. And I print the path at the end:

```
def mazeSolver(self,x,y,path):
    if self.maze2d[x][y] == '.':
        self.maze2d[x][y] = "_"
    if self.maze2d[x][y] == "E":
        print path
        return True
    else:
        if x < len(self.maze2d)-1: 
            if self.maze2d[x+1][y] in ['.','E']:
                self.mazeSolver(x+1,y,path + "S")
        if x > 0:
            if self.maze2d[x-1][y]  in ['.','E']:
                self.mazeSolver(x-1,y,path + "N")
        if y < len(var1.maze2d[x])-1: 
            if self.maze2d[x][y+1]  in ['.','E']:
                self.mazeSolver(x,y+1,path + "E")
        if y > 0:
            if self.maze2d[x][y-y]  in ['.','E']:
                self.mazeSolver(x,y-1,path + "W")

>>> var1.mazeSolver(x,y,"")
ESEESEE
>>>> var1.maze2d
[['S', '_', '_', '*', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '_', '_', '_', '*', '.'],
 ['_', '_', '*', '_', '_', 'E']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will never reach the end, since it only visits locations with the value `.`, and the end has the value `E`.